# std::is_trivially_copyable_v on virtual function

Tags: c++

I try following code, it just prints `false`.

```
class A
{
    virtual void func() {}
};

std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<A>;
```

Why does virtual function influence copy? virtual table pointer can just trivially copy.

Comment: See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable). Virtual functions make classes non-trivial.

Comment: *virtual table pointer can just trivially copy.* -- There is no mandate that virtual functions are implemented this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [class.prop](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#1.2)

> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> > where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator is trivial ...

And from [class.copy.assign](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#9.1)

> A copy/move assignment operator for class X is trivial if ...
>
> > class X has no virtual functions ...

So your class `A` is not *trivially-copyable* since it has a virtual function `func`.